# Solidary? Solidaritous? Solidarious? Adjective for having "solidarity"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been wondering this for a time, especially in moments when I would like to use this mystery word. You can say someone exhibits "solidarity", but what is the adjective for someone who does as part of their nature? I keep wanting to just use something like in the title above, namely: "`solidary`", "`solidaritous`", or "`solidarious`", but I know these don't exist (my spellcheck confirms it). I'm guessing there is a word with another stem that expresses the concept, and for sure I am aware of the word "loyal" being along those lines, but it doesn't quite express the same thing. So, is there a word for this? There is in Spanish, but the closest translation I see is "`sympathetic`", but that's definitely not the same intensity as the word "solidarity" would require.

Comment: The right word is _solid_. If your group's got solidarity, it's solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[solidary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/solidary) does exist. Maybe it just isn't included in your spellcheck.

But coming back to your question, there is also a word for having solidarity: [solidaric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solidaric)

Comment: Interesting.` Solidary` in that same Merriam-Webster link does indeed show up, it makes sense that my spellcheck wouldn't have it, since it seems to be a legal term. And `solidaric`! Nice find! Ugly word, but it's what I was looking for, thanks!